# JPA Repository is not visible in my project

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-mvc, spring-data-jpa

I am having trouble in starting my Spring Boot project, as I get an error that says the fact that I have not defined a bean of type Repository in my project, even though I had. This is my code:

Controller:

```
package com.example.demo1.controller;

import com.example.demo1.entities.Book;
import com.example.demo1.service.BookService;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

import java.util.List;

@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api")
public class BookController {
    @Autowired
    BookService bookService;

    @GetMapping(value="/books/all")
    public ResponseEntity<List<Book>> getAllBooks(){
        return  ResponseEntity.ok(bookService.getAllBooks());
    }

}
```

Service

```
package com.example.demo1.service;

import com.example.demo1.entities.Book;
import com.example.demo1.repository.BookJPARepository;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

import java.util.List;

@Service
public class BookService {
    @Autowired
    BookJPARepository bookJPARepository;

    public List<Book> getAllBooks(){
        return bookJPARepository.findAll();
    }
}
```

Repository

```
package com.example.demo1.repository;

import com.example.demo1.entities.Book;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

@Repository
public interface BookJPARepository extends JpaRepository<Book, Long> {
}
```

pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.5</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>demo1</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>demo1</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>17</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jdbc</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-rest</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-j</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <image>
                        <builder>paketobuildpacks/builder-jammy-base:latest</builder>
                    </image>
                    <excludes>
                        <exclude>
                            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                        </exclude>
                    </excludes>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Entity:

```
    package com.example.demo1.entities;

import jakarta.persistence.*;
import lombok.Data;

@Entity
@Table(name = "books", schema = "books")
@Data
public class Book {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "book_id", nullable = false)
    private Long id;
    @Basic
    @Column(name = "book_name", nullable = false, length = 255)
    private String title;
    @Basic
    @Column(name = "book_author", nullable = false, length = 255)
    private String author;
    @Basic
    @Column(name = "book_publishing_house", nullable = false, length = 255)
    private String publishing_house;
    @Basic
    @Column(name = "book_price")
    private float price;

    public Book(String book_name, String book_author, String book_price, String book_publishing_house) {
    this.title=book_name;
    this.author=book_author;
    this.price=Float.parseFloat(book_price);
    this.publishing_house=book_publishing_house;
    }
}
```

Application is this one:

```
    package com.example.demo1;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.EnableAutoConfiguration;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceAutoConfiguration;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;

@SpringBootApplication
@EnableAutoConfiguration(exclude={DataSourceAutoConfiguration.class})
@ComponentScan
@Configuration
public class Demo1Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Demo1Application.class, args);
    }

}
```

The error is this one:

---

APPLICATION FAILED TO START

---

Description:

Field bookJPARepository in com.example.demo1.service.BookService required a bean of type 'com.example.demo1.repository.BookJPARepository' that could not be found.

The injection point has the following annotations:
- @org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)

Action:

Consider defining a bean of type 'com.example.demo1.repository.BookJPARepository' in your configuration.

**Have I missed something? Could you help me please?**

I expected that my app should start. Have I missed any dependency when creating the project with Spring initialzr?

Comment: Where is your application class that is annotated with `@SpringBootApplication`? It should be in the package `com.example.demo1`. Note that if you put it in a package that is not higher in the hierarchy than the packages that contain the repository and the controller, Spring Boot will not find it automatically.

Comment: I added it now. I had it in that package.

Comment: Why do you have this line: `@EnableAutoConfiguration(exclude={DataSourceAutoConfiguration.class})`? Remove it. Also, `@ComponentScan` and `@Configuration` are not necessary on your application class.

Comment: I removed the @EnableAutoConfiguration and now I get these errors when I start the project:                                                                                                             
    Unable to create requested service [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.spi.JdbcEnvironment] due to: Unable to resolve name [org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect] as strategy [org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect]

Comment: Remove `@ EnableAutoConfiguration`, `@ComponentScan` and `@Configuration`. You disabled the database, JPA needs a database. The error you get about the dialect is because you are following some old tutorial or guide. Use `MySQLDialect` instead (which is for Hibernate6).

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77474190/how-to-debug-spring-boot-autoconfiguration/77474191 might be helpful in debugging this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@EnableAutoConfiguration(exclude={DataSourceAutoConfiguration.class})
remove this line it will work, it disables database