# How to debug Spring Boot autoconfiguration

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-autoconfiguration

A common problem pattern when working with Spring Boot is that a bean is missing, although that one expects it to be created by Spring Boot.

How does one debug such a scenario?
How does one find out why that bean wasn't created as expected!

*Note: I created this question and it's answer from a [question asking this for a special case](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77455318/spring-boot-cant-find-repository-bean). I hope this is helpful in a wide array of scenarios.*

Answer (score 6):

1. Enable Spring Boot's debugging by adding `debug=true` to your `application.properties` file.

   This creates log output during startup. For each auto-configuration available it contains the information if it "matched" or not, i.e. if it's preconditions are fulfilled, and what these conditions are.
2. Look especially in the section `Negative matches` of the output for auto-configurations that should happen but don't. Searching for relevant technologies in the log is a good idea.
3. auto-configurations you found in the previous step might hint at other auto-configurations that didn't get activated. For these repeat step 2.

The following is an example of that search for https://github.com/iosenberg/todo/commit/c4cfbf63132e251ce98cfe02178bd48cc447aac7
Which was referenced in [Spring boot can't find Repository bean](https://stackoverflow.com/q/77455318/66686)

The missing bean is a Spring Data JDBC repository. Therefore *datasource* or *jdbc* come to mind as first search terms.
Searching for *JDBC* yields the following results that seem
relevant:

```
   DataSourceAutoConfiguration matched:
      - @ConditionalOnClass found required classes 'javax.sql.DataSource', 'org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.embedded.EmbeddedDatabaseType' (OnClassCondition)
      - @ConditionalOnMissingBean (types: io.r2dbc.spi.ConnectionFactory; SearchStrategy: all) did not find any beans (OnBeanCondition)

   DataSourceTransactionManagerAutoConfiguration matched:
      - @ConditionalOnClass found required classes 'org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate', 'org.springframework.transaction.TransactionManager' (OnClassCondition)
```

This looks like there is a `DataSource`, which just demonstrates that you shouldn't stop at the first match.

The next match is:

```
   DataSourceInitializationConfiguration:
      Did not match:
         - @ConditionalOnSingleCandidate (types: javax.sql.DataSource; SearchStrategy: all) did not find any beans (OnBeanCondition)
      Matched:
         - @ConditionalOnClass found required class 'org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.init.DatabasePopulator' (OnClassCondition)
```

So, `DataSourceAutoConfiguration` did run, but we still don't seem to have a `DataSource` bean. From this we learn that there is an important difference between a class being available and a bean of that type being available. Kind of obvious when you say it out loud, yet easy to miss when you look at some log file.

The rest of the search turns up just more stuff that doesn't work, which is either irrelevant, or not surprising if there is no `DataSource` bean.  Therefore I switched to searching for *datasource* in the log.

That returns tons of hits. But the first one in the `Negative matches` was really helpful.

```
   DataSourceAutoConfiguration.EmbeddedDatabaseConfiguration:
      Did not match:
         - EmbeddedDataSource did not find embedded database (DataSourceAutoConfiguration.EmbeddedDatabaseCondition)
```

So no embedded database found! What database is it trying to use?
Checking the `application.properties` for a JDBC url shows there is none.
Checking the dependencies shows there is an embedded database, but only with scope `test`, therefore for the main program there is no JDBC driver available.
Fixing that by making the in memory database dependency available for the main application solved the proble.